# panelgroup based on an arrayList - editing the arraylist and updating the panelgroup from within

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

This is a follow up question to: [Dynamically updating a4j:repeat using data from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109729/dynamically-updating-a4jrepeat-using-data-from-form)

I now have 2 selects and next to them a commandbutton. When the button is pressed, the ul-list beneath the selects is updated with a line including the values of both selects and a remove button.

When I press the remove button, I want to remove the line (name+use rights pair) from the bean side and from the view. The pair is correctly removed from the arraylist on the bean side, but the ul-list is not updated. When I press F5, the element is removed from the list though.

How do I render the panelgroup again when I press the remove button?

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{assetUploadForm.currentGroupName}" valueChangeListener="#{assetUploadForm.groupNameChanged}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{assetUploadForm.groupNames}" />
   <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{assetUploadForm.currentGroupRW}" valueChangeListener="#{assetUploadForm.groupRWChanged}">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="R" itemLabel="Read"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="W" itemLabel="Write"/>
   <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<a4j:commandButton action="#{assetUploadForm.addGroupRights}" value="add group" render="groupList"/>
<h:panelGroup id="groupList">
<ul>
  <a4j:repeat value="#{assetUploadForm.groupPermissions}" var="permission">
    <li>
      <h:outputText value="#{permission.group.groupName}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <h:outputText value="#{permission.permissionMode}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a4j:commandButton action="#{assetUploadForm.removeGroupPermission}" render="groupList" value="remove">
        <a4j:param value="#{permission.group.groupName}" assignTo="#{assetUploadForm.permissionToRemove}"/>
      </a4j:commandButton>                      
    </li>
  </a4j:repeat> 
</ul>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I tried various things for a day, give up and ask, then try something else and it works. :)

adding execute="@this" to the remove commandButton resolved this issue. I'll add the answer later today, I can't add it yet because I don't have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding execute="@this" to the remove commandButton resolved this issue.